# Where are system speech voices stored in MacOS Monterey?

Tags: accessibility, customization, text-to-speech

The default voices in Monterey are stored in `/System/Library/SpeechBase/Voices/`. I used **System Preferences > Accessibility > System Voice > Customize...** to install a few more US, UK, and novelty voices, but I can't find where they are stored.

Prior to Monterey, the voices resided in `/System/Library/Speech/Voices/`, which still exists but is empty. The `/System/Library/SpeechBase/` directory is apparently new with Monterey, but it does not contain the additional voices I installed. Where are these voices being stored?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked, but as downloadable assets, I suspect they will be somewhere in `/System/Library/AssetsV2/`

There are subfolders whose names include `VoiceServices`, `MacInTalkVoiceAssets`, `SiriTextToSpeech`, and other relevant words.

The AssetsV2 folder is where Apple stores optional/additional content, like Dictionaries, Fonts, and voices that can be downloaded from Apple.